# controller test not passing in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

My controller test isn't passing. I have a before_acton in my ReviewsController that tests for a current user. If there is none, it shouldn't complete the create action and redirect. But it does create it, despite the session[:user_id] being nil. Here is my code:

```
it "doesnt create review if there is valid input, but not authenticated" do
  video = Video.create(title: "new title", description: "new description")
  review = Review.create(content: "content1", rating: 1)
  expect(Review.count).to eq(0)
end
```

In my ReviewsController:

```
def create
    @video = Video.find(params[:video_id])
    @review = Review.new(parameters)
    rating = params[:review][:rating]
    content = params[:review][:content]
    @review.content = content
    @review.rating = rating
    @review.user_id = current_user.id
    @review.video = @video
    @review.save

    redirect_to @video
end
```

i have a before_action in the Reviews controller that test if a user is authenticated. If the session[:user_id] is nil, then it redirects to the sign_in_path. Here are the methods:

```
def current_user
  @current_user = User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
end


def require_user
  redirect_to sign_in_path unless current_user
end
```

in my reviews_controller_spec.rb file, it shouldn't create the review, because it shouldn't get past the before_action :require_user

Why is the review object still being created? Why doesn't the before_action filter stop it? The test fails and just says it expected Review.count to be 0, but got 1.

Comment: You're not actually calling your controller in that spec... just creating records and checking if they were created.

Comment: I tried "post :create, content: "new content", rating: 3" instead of "review = Review.create(content: "content1", rating: 1)", but that gave me an error "No routes matches :action=>"create"", yet there is definitely a create action in my controller.

Comment: did you create test database and data is there creating ?

Comment: If this is a controller test it needs to be under `specs/controller` directory, and specify which controller with `RSpec.describe ReviewsController do..end`   Then the `post :create...` will be sent to the right path.

Comment: Do you actually have a route to `ReviewsController#create`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# config/routes.rb
resources :videos, shallow: true do
  resources :reviews
end
```

There is no need to bind params to attributes 1-1. In fact doing so will make you controllers excessively verbose plus its boring as hell to type it out.

```
class ReviewsController < ApplicationController

  before_filter :authenticate_user!

  def create
    @video = Video.find(params[:video_id])
    @review = current_user.reviews.new(review_params) do |r|
      r.video = @video 
    end
  end

  private 
    # this is mass assignment protection
    def review_params
      params.require(:review).permit(:rating, :content)
    end
end
```

If you decide to roll you own authentication (which is a bad idea) don't repeat it across your controllers and views:

```
module AuthenticationHelper
  def current_user
     @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
  end

  def sign_in(user)
     @current_user = user
     session[:user_id] = user.id
  end

  def sign_out
     @current_user = nil
     reset_session
  end

  def authenticate_user!
    raise User::NotAuthorized unless current_user
  end
end
```

A key point is that a opt out security model is far better since it eliminates the risk of leaving a route open by omission:

```
class ApplicationController
  include AuthenticationHelper
  rescue_from User::NotAuthorized, with: :deny_access!

  # use skip_before_action :authenticate_user! if 
  # you don't want a route / controller to require auth.
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  private
    def deny_access!
      redirect_to root_path
    end 
end
```

So to test ReviewsController we would do:

```
describe ReviewsController do
  let(:user) { User.create(name: 'joe') }
  let(:video) { Video.create(name: 'Cats Gone Wild') }
  describe "#create" do

    let(:valid_attributes) { { video_id: video, title: "new title", description: "new description" }  }

    context "when unauthorized" do
      it "does not create a review" do
        expect { post :create, valid_attributes }.to_not change(Review, :count)
      end
    end

    context "when authorized" do
      before { subject.stub(:current_user) { user } }

      # ...
    end
  end
end
```

Key points here:

- use `let` to setup test dependencies
- use `expect { action }.to change` to test if an action alters the DB. Testing for `.count == 0` can lead to false positives.